# Javascript singleton inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, singleton

I would like to keep a single parent class. all clild classes that inherit the parent class will be able to share the same parent class object. How that can be achieved?

```
var ParentClass = function(){
    this.a = null;
}

ParentClass.prototype.setA = function(inp){
    this.a = inp;
}

ParentClass.prototype.getA = function(){
    console.log("get a "+this.a);
}

// Clild Class

var ClassB = function(){}

ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);

var b = new ClassB();
b.setA(10);
b.getA(); //it will return 10


//Another clild Class
var ClassC = function(){}

ClassC.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
var c = new ClassC();
c.getA(); //I want 10 here.
```

I understand, as for the second clild class the parent class is instantiating again that is why I can't access the old object. How I can achieve this singleton inheritance in Javascript? Any idea?

Comment: I think you can leave away all the inheritance from your question. The singleton pattern doesn't even work currently if `b` and `c` were instances of `ParentClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put such static values somewhere else. `this` is the current instance, and that's not where you want to create a new property. Choices are:

- `ParentClass.prototype` (as demonstrated by @bfavaretto), which will lead to all instances inheriting and being able to overwrite it
- a scoped variable (implementing the revealing module pattern basically):

  ```
  (function() {
      var a;
      ParentClass.prototype.setA = function(inp){
          a = inp;
      };
      ParentClass.prototype.getA = function(){
          console.log("get a "+a);
          return a;
      };
  }());
  ```
- the `ParentClass` function object itself:

  ```
  ParentClass.prototype.setA = function(inp){
      ParentClass.a = inp;
  };
  ParentClass.prototype.getA = function(){
      console.log("get a "+ParentClass.a);
      return ParentClass.a;
  };
  ```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `getA` from any instance, the value of `this` inside it will point to the instance itself. You can achieve what you're looking for if your change the setter code to this:

```
ParentClass.prototype.setA = function(inp){
    ParentClass.prototype.a = inp;
}
```

Note that calling `getA` from an instance of ParentClass will return `null`, and the constructor defines an own property `a` that will shadow the one from the prototype.